# laravel eloquent query relationship

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, orm, eloquent

My table structure is as following:

resumes
-id
-...

educations
-id
-resume_id
-degree_id
-...

degrees
-id
-name

My resume model is like this:

```
class Resume extends Eloquent {
  public function degree(){
    return $this->hasManyThrough('Degree', 'Education', 'resume_id', 'degree_id');
  }
}
```

The query formed is this:

```
select `education`.*, `degrees`.`resume_id` from `education` inner join `degrees` on`degrees`.`id` = `education`.`degree_id` where `degrees`.`resume_id` = 36035
```

But what I want is this :   where education.resume_id = 36035

Or is there any other better way to chain the query so that I could directly access the degree table from resume like this $resume->degree
I've even tried eager loading approach but didn't able to retrieve data by chaining

Answer (score 1):

I think it would be better to use `belongsToMany`.

Possibly something like this:

```
public function degree()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('Degree')->withPivot('resume_id');
}
```